# Windows 10 High contrast - border width

Tags: windows-10, border

When enabling High Contrast theme in Windows 10, for some reason, the whole system is filled with white boxes. Almost every UI element has this ugly white border (mainly start menu & taskbar). There are no settings for border width tweaking. I googled my problem but did not find anything. So, I was wondering if this issue can be solved through Registry manipulation.

Here are the examples of these white outlines:

[image]

[image]